# Git on MacOS restoring file after commit when doing a git rm

Tags: git, macos, macos-high-sierra

Running MacOs High Sierra 10.13.4 and git version 2.17.0.

Here's my workflow:

- `git rm ./some/file.out`
- Run `git status` see that the delete for `./some/file.out` is waiting to be committed
- Check `ls ./some/` and see the file has been deleted
- Run `git commit` and see message one file was deleted

However:

- If I then run `git status` I see the file still there but untracked.
- When run `git clean -df` on the untracked file it gets removed and doesn't return.

I've also tried

- Delete the file with non-git `rm ./some/file.out`
- Run `git add .` then `git commit` and see file deleted message
- Run `git status` and shows file still present, but untracked

It seems this just started happening recently.

Here's my git config:

```
credential.helper=osxkeychain
core.hookspath=/Users/myname/.git_hooks
core.excludesfile=/Users/myname/.gitignore
user.email=myname@somewhere.com
color.ui=true
color.branch=true
color.status=true
color.diff=true
color.interactive=true
color.grep=true
color.pager=true
color.decorate=true
color.showbranch=true
alias.pt=!git push -u origin `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
alias.co=checkout
alias.cob=checkout -B
alias.b=branch
alias.bd=branch -D
```

What could potential be going on--specifically, has anyone else seen something like this and found it to be git related?

Just deleting files (non-git repo files) in the terminal does not have this behavior.

Comment: Are you sure that the file is not auto-generated by another program?

Comment: I made sure my IDE isn't running (in case that was causing the futz), but nothing should be referencing the directory I'm in.  To test if this happened outside my user home,  I created a directory in my `/tmp` and initiallized a repo in that folder.  Added some files and observed the same functionality.   Nothing that I'm aware of should be referencing a new directory I manually added to `/tmp`.  Also, the only time I've ever seen this happen is via git.  Normal deletes of file with `rm foo.out` just stay deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poked around my `~/.git_hooks`.   Looks like a script being called in my `~/.git_hooks/pre-commit.d` folder is to blame.

Not sure what exactly the script is doing (or was supposed to do), but when I remove the script the `git rm && git commit` functionality works as expected--no more files risen from the dead!

Comment: Git does not look for `.d` directories, but you probably have a `~/.git_hooks/pre-commit` that does look in the `.d` directory. Where did you get these hooks? Why did you install them? :-)

Comment: Yes, you're correct the `~/.git_hooks/pre-commit` is basically just looking for files in a `.d` directory.  Looked into them, they're config file checks my company uses to make sure you don't fudged up the automated build and deploy for your deployable when commit.  Why they were causing this odd behavior was due to several different libraries the script used being out of date.  Not sure which one exactly affected things in this way--once I updated everything and put the script back everything worked fine.